# The program 'sed' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing [sed: not found]

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I was trying to create my own program in the /usr/local/bin.

During the process I messed something up and now anytime I press enter or type anything in the command line, I get this stupid message....!

***The program 'sed' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing***

How can I get rid of "sed" or whatever it is.

[image]

What I have discovered thus far about 'sed', it is SED Stream Editor which manipulates text.  I used to use it within my .bashrc for git parsing and coloring of text.  I now disabled the git parsing function within my .bashrc.

**How can I get 'sed' installed again?**

I ran `apt-get install sed` ... It tells me sed is already the newest version.  SED is now causing me more issues.  My git commands are breaking and even my apt-get remove and updates sometimes breaks as well.

This is another example of what SED is causing me since SED is not found

```
/etc/grub.d/00_header: 1: /etc/grub.d/00_header: sed: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-ex....
```

**Which sed**

When I run `which sed` ... It comes out completely blank, it doesn't output something like this `/usr/bin/sed`.

Here is my current PATH=.., which I pulled from /ect/environment

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: Closing/reopening the terminal emulator does not help? Maybe a reboot will fix it...

Comment: How did you end up affecting sed in there?

Comment: Did you edit `bashrc` file?

Comment: No... Closing of the terminal and/or restarting does not clear th e issue.

Comment: I don't even know what 'sed' is.  Never seen it before.  I was adding a program to /usr/local/bin and when I tried running it, I was getting not found.  So I tried to source and also update the $PATH and somehow got SED.  Maybe a mash on a keyboard?

Comment: What program? Its name? How did you run it? How did you update the $PATH? what is your $PATH now? please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/578140/edit) your question and add your replies in body of your question.

Comment: You haven't *got* `sed`. The problem is that something is trying to *run* `sed`, and you *don't* have it. What happens when you type `cat ~/.bashrc`? There's probably a reference to `sed` somewhere in there.

Comment: show us the script you are writing. If you're using Ubuntu, you have sed. (stream editor) do this command $which sed

Comment: I have SED within my .bashrc during my parse_git_branch() ... BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'` ... I am not sure how I edited $PATH the firs time around. But I made sure .bashrc had no reference of PATH and I also made sure my /etc/environment was clean

Comment: @jOh  The script I wrote has nothing with SED in it.  SED is a result of non-sense I did after I tried to get my script to run from command line.  I don't want to show the script and lead people down the wrong path.

Comment: That attitude "help me but I don't want to show you what I did" makes the problem harder to solve.

Comment: @guntbert I added the script.  There was no attitude, I just want to be efficient.  I am 99.9% sure this script has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `sed` is from the `sed` package. Reinstall it: `sudo apt-get install sed`. Though I don't know what insanity led to `sed` being removed.

Comment: @muru  unfortunately... I can't do the standard apt-get install sed... it still never gets installed even with SUDO.  I have no idea what is igoing on.  SED also effects when I press TAB to auto complete things too.

Comment: Can you post the error message you get when trying to install it?

Comment: Have you tried to install `sed` from tty (Alt+Ctrl+F1)? Alternatively you can try from `xterm`

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and copy-paste all the output starting from `sudo apt-get install sed` to your prompt...

Comment: If it says sed's the newest version, try reinstalling it: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall sed`.

Comment: @muru - It didn't error out when reinstalling sed but it also didn't fix the issue.  I still get the same error message of sed: not found during other apt-get remove attempts which follow after --reinstall

Comment: the path you showed, which you say you got from `/etc/environment`, is probably not the effective path. Can you show the output of doing `echo $PATH` ? Also, if you say `sed` is installed correctly, it should be in `/bin/`. What happens if you do `/bin/sed`? What about `ls /bin/sed` ? (Incidentally, `ls` also lives in `/bin/` so if it's a path issue, then `ls` will also not work).

Comment: the $PATH and the /etc/environmens were the same.  When i typed 'which sed' it was blank, so it was never found anywhere within my $PATH directories.  I posted my solution below already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My Solution:**

I copied a `sed` from another ubuntu server I was running. `scp me@server:/bin/sed /bin/sed`

Answer (score 3):

Besides [copying the binary](https://askubuntu.com/a/581399/22949) from another machine and hoping it is the correct version, this can also be solved by using `apt` or `apt-get` to install the `sed` package **and passing the `--reinstall` option** so that the `.deb` file will be downloaded and installed even though Ubuntu's package manager *thinks* it is already present.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall sed
```

This works with `apt-get` instead of `apt`, too. It uninstalls and reinstalls the package in a single step. The situation in this problem is that **the `se` package is already installed but the executable has been deleted**, so reinstalling solves that. Without the `--reinstall` flag, the package manager assumes nothing has to be done, because the package is installed already.

You can run `sudo apt update` first if you want, though it will not typically be necessary in this case, unless you've modified your software sources without doing so. You can pass the `--purge` flag too if you want but it's unnecessary here, since that just causes conffiles for the package to be removed when it is uninstalled.

`sed` is a utility that programs are generally allowed to assume exists and to rely on themselves. As you noticed, the scripts that run when installing, removing, or upgrading software can use `sed`. That's the source of your specific error messages. *In theory*  APT or `dpkg` could rely on it directly and be unable to reinstall it. In practice, this does not appear to happen, and I don't expect it to. I've tested this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I cannot think of any situation where replacing the binary fixes the problem but reinstalling neither works nor shows an error immediately (see comments on the post). Although I cannot be 100% sure that these instructions would work for you--because perhaps more was broken than documented in the question--they should generally work at least as reliably as manually replacing `/bin/sed` for others who experience this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Anyway the simple quick fix would be to create softlink for the sed in the machine. first, check for 'which sed'

```
which sed
```

then create softlink to the above result

```
ln -sf /bin/sed /usr/bin/sed
```

Hope this would help!

Comment: I had sed, but no symlink in /usr/bin/sed, the reinstall didn't create it either, so this was just what I needed